# Flipping a view only works when hiding, but not when showing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uikit

I'm using the iCarousel library to show a coverflow-like UI. Animating the iCarousel subviews directly tends to blow up, so I create a wrapper for my animation and stick a subview inside of it which looks like the tapped cover. Then I hide the actual iCarousel view, and animate the fake cover on top of it.

I'm using `UIView`'s `transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:` method, but I'm running into some trouble. When animating another view onscreen *for the first time*, the view appears without any animation. When animating out, the view correctly flips and hides.

My view hierarchy is as follows:

- main view, loaded from a nib
- wrapper view

  - view to transition from
  - view to transition to

The view I'm transitioning to is a UINavigationController's view which contains a UITableViewController subclass. Instead of the initial animation, the UINavigationController appears and then the view grows upward a little, as if it's taking over the space otherwise occupied by a status bar.

Any idea why the table view might be animating like this? (I suspect containment APIs and/or `wantsFullscreen`, although I'm not explicitly using them. I simply install the views into the wrapper via `addSubview:`.)

Here's my "flip in" code, that animates every time but the first:

```
- (void) flipInWithCompletion:(MBTransitionCompletion)completion {
BOOL displayingPrimary = [self isDisplayingPrimaryView];

UIView *frontView = [self frontView];
UIView *backView = [self backView];
UIView *wrapperView = [self wrapperView];

[wrapperView addSubview:frontView];

[UIView transitionWithView:wrapperView
                  duration:0.8
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                animations:^{
                    [wrapperView addSubview:backView];
                    [frontView removeFromSuperview];
                }
                completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    [self setIsDisplayingPrimaryView:!displayingPrimary];
                    if (completion) {
                        completion();
                    }
                }
 ];
```

}

What might cause the table view to grow instead of allowing the wrapper to flip?

**Edit:**

I've made [a video](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/8372230/NSNBug.mov) demoing the exact problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the view isn't properly loaded before it starts to animate in. I think I remember having a similar problem before. Try adding it to your view first, then remove it, and try to animate it into place to see if that fixes it.

That's not really a solution though, but it should give you a clue as to what might be wrong.

Comment: Yea, adding and removing the views definitely helps, but the fake cover doesn't appear on first flip. Seems like an initialization glitch of some kind. I clearly need to read the docs. :-)